# ORDER BY with multiple columns not working with Join in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I am working with mysql and i want to use ORDER BY with two different column,But right now "ORDER BY"
is working only for 1 column not two,How can i do this ?

Here is my mysql query

```
select count(DISTINCT p.id) cnt,m.merchantName,l.`name` locality,c.name city,bc.`category_url`,
            m.merchantId,mi.src,m.url,group_concat(psm.slot) slots,min(p.sp) sp,group_concat(distinct mi.src) imgs,group_concat( distinct mi.type) imgs_type,m.cuisines,
            p.ptype,m.logo,bc.categoryName,m.profile
            from products p
            LEFT JOIN product_slot_mapping psm
            on p.id=psm.productId
            left join merchants m
            on p.`merchantId`=m.merchantId
            left join locality l
            on m.localityId=l.localityId
            left join city c
            on l.cityId=c.cityId
            LEFT JOIN area a
            on c.areaId=a.area_id
            left join `business_category` bc
            on m.`businessCategoryId`=bc.`businessCategoryId`
            left join merchant_image mi
            on m.merchantid=mi.merchantId and mi.isActive=1 and mi.type=3  and mi.isActive=1
            left join product_tags pt
            on pt.businessCategoryId=m.businessCategoryId and p.ptype=pt.id
            left join product_properities_mapping ppm on
            p.id=ppm.productId
            where   p.ptype in (5,6) and  p.merchantId in (15538,15696) and  a.url='chandigarh' and p.status=1 and m.`isActive`=1 and salesTo>=NOW()  and bc.category_url='salons-and-spa'  
            group by m.merchantId having cnt>0 order by p.sp DESC,m.merchantName ASC limit 100
```

Comment: You need to use order by p.sp , m.marchantName DESC

Comment: have you tried it like this  - order by  m.merchantName, p.sp DESC

Comment: @Adamszsz: i want p.sp "ASC" And m.merchantName "DESC" but with my current query 1 orderby working instead of two, so how can i do this ?

Comment: @AdarshBaranwal: i want order by with two columns 1 for DESC (p.sp) and 2nd for ASC(p.merchantName) , but current query working for single order by not multiple,hope you understand my point

Comment: @Ritika yeah i got you point can you tell me which one is working?

Comment: @AdarshBaranwal: "p.sp DESC" is working but "m.merchantName ASC" not working

Comment: There's no `p.sp` in your query, there is however a `min(p.sp) sp`. Please show us the (your definition of wrong ordering) result you're getting now and your expected result.

Comment: @FaNo_FN: let me explain , actually my order by is working with one columns only instead of two columns , Order by is working with "p.sp" ASC/DESC but not working for "m.merchantName" ASC/DESC at same time,Hope you understand my point

Comment: Before worrying about the order of your results, you should worry about the results themselves. Your query is invalid. You `GROUP BY m.merchantId`, so you get one result row per merchant. What then is the `p.ptype` you are selecting? A merchant has many products. Which of the products' ptypes do you want to show? Same for the `p.sp` you want to order by. Which of the merchant's products should this be referring to? Make sure you have `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` in MySQL, so you get an error on invalid queries rather than arbitrary results.

Comment: Aside from this: Why all the outer joins? Do you expect to find merchants without addresses? If so, be aware that `where ... a.url='chandigarh'` removes all outer-joined rows again and turns all those joins into inner joins.

Comment: I understand but I need a "before and after" to make sure that what you're aiming for is something that can be achieved.

Comment: I feel like we don't have a [mcve].  **Needs Debugging Details** in the form of a db-fiddle.

Comment: Or at _least_ a clear definition of what you mean by "not working."  What did you expect to happen?  What _actually_ happened?

Comment: @RyanM: actually , current query working with "one" column (p.sp) instead of two (m.merchantName) , this is the problem

Comment: Again, please define "working" and "not working."  What did you expect to happen with two columns? What _actually_ happened?

Comment: Another thing that has me wondering: What is `having cnt>0` supposed to do? You select `from products p` and `count(DISTINCT p.id)`. How could you ever end up with a count less than zero? It is just not possible. Your `HAVING` clause is not doing anything hence.

Comment: @Ritika: You are supposed to give an example. Instead of an order of, say, 2|Jane, 2|John, 1|Anne, 1|Jeff you are getting what? The result rows mixed like 1|Jeff, 2|John, 2|Jane, 1|Anne? Or a syntax error? Or what else? And have you read all comments? Your query simply is **invalid**. So get this fixed, before worrying about the sorting. You cannot `order by p.sp`, because you grouped by merchant. Do you understand this?

Comment: @RyanM: working means "sorting properly" (showing result correct) means getting result according to sp (selling price) ASC/DESC and "not working" means result getting Incorrectly/wrong means getting result only according to " p.sp " but not getting result according to "m.merchantName" ASC/DESC, Hope now you understand my point

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner : actually i am working with exist project, Means query not wrote by me i am just trying to use "orderby" with existing query,in other words i am working/editing existing/previous/old query,Hope you understand my point now

Comment: @ritika post current & expected output because I think it does sort by p.sp first and then by the merchant. I think you are expecting some other result.

Comment: @SibiKandathil: no you are right, i want to sort with two different columns only

Comment: @But the query is *invalid*. Because you are not working in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode, you allow this to get unnoticed. You should *never* do this. MySQL silently applies `ANY_VALUE` on `p.sp`: `ORDER BY ANY_VALUE(p.sp)`. This arbitrary chosen `sp` does not appear in your select clause. You get thus an order that you cannot see or verify. It's just like showing a ist of first names, but the order is on last names. The results will look jumbled.

Comment: How about this example @Ritika , does it look right? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bab7db835596c038ff6c72607a06c9c . If you want, maybe you want to make the data a bit similar with what you're working with, just modify the fiddle then click run. It will generate a new link and you can post that new link here for us to refer.

Comment: As to "i am working/editing existing/previous/old query,Hope you understand my point now": No, I don't understand your point. If you are working on a query, no matter how old, and you see (or are told) that it is invalid, then fix it. "I am just adding something [to that invalid query and I don't care what that does to its existing shortcomings]" is not an attitude that I'd appreciate.

Comment: Your question got closed. This is because you are seeing a result list that we don't see and you failed to tell us what you are seeing. It was like You: "My telephone book is not ordered by last name and first name" We: "What makes you think so?" You: "It is not ordered by last name and first name" We: "Give us an example" You: "It's an old book". How was that supposed to help us help you?

Comment: As long as this is closed you won't get any more answers, but you were lucky to get an answer before this got closed. Next time put yourself in our place and give us all the information we need. In this case your request lacked an example of what you call "not working".

Answer (score 2):

MySQL allows invalid queries when not working in full group by mode. So always make sure to have `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` when working with mySQL.

This setting influences how MySQL deals with invalid aggreation. Here is a simple example:

```
select employee_name from employees group by department;
```

We group by department here and hence get one result row per department. But we select the employee name. Which? There are many employees in a department. MySQL should raise an error, and it does when working in full group by mode. When not working in that mode, however, MySQL silently "fixes" your invalid query thus:

```
select ANY_VALUE(employee_name) from employees group by department;
```

i.e. it simply picks one employee per department arbitrarily.

Now, if you have this:

```
select department, min(employee_name)
from employees
group by department
order by employee_name;
```

Then MySQL converts this into

```
select department, min(employee_name)
from employees
group by department
order by any_value(employee_name);
```

So lets say that department A has employees John and Tom and department B has Max and Jane. You may expect this result: B|Jane, A|John, because these are the minimum names per department and Jane comes before John in the alphabet. But the order is on an arbitrary employee name for the department, so you could as well get this result: A|John, B|Jane, if the DBMS happens to order on John and Max. The result seems unordered, but this is because we order by something we don't show.

Now look at your query:

```
select ... min(p.sp) sp ...
group by m.merchantId
order by p.sp DESC, m.merchantName
```

MySQL turns this into

```
select ... min(p.sp) sp ...
group by m.merchantId
order by ANY_VALUE(p.sp) DESC, m.merchantName
```

and the above said applies. If you want to order by the shown `sp`, then order by it:

```
select ... min(p.sp) sp ...
group by m.merchantId
order by min(p.sp) DESC, m.merchantName
```

`order by sp DESC, m.merchantName` (i.e. `sp` instead of `p.sp`) should also work, because I think the alias name would have precedence over the column name in `ORDER BY`, but  wouldn't rely on this. It is a bad idea to use a column name as an alias name like in `min(p.sp) sp`, because this can lead to confusion and mistakes.

(You should also replace `select ... p.ptype ...` by `select ... any_value(p.ptype) ...` yourself to make it obvious what s hapening in your query. Then set full group by mode to see whether your query is finally valid.)

Answer (score 0):

In case of sorting with two columns, MySQL treats the first field as primary and the latter as secondary. Therefore, it first sorts the primary and then the second one. you can refer to this [link](https://www.techbeamers.com/mysql-order-by/) that's why it seems that its working with the `p.sp` and then sorting it to according `m.merchantName` so you have to write the column names according to the priority .

Comment: not understand! kindly tell me is something wrong with my query ? if yes then can you write correct query so i can check ? or is this possible to sort with two different columns with same time ?

Comment: please try this once :  order by m.merchantName, p.sp DESC

Comment: its actually sorting with both the columns but its taking p.sp as primary sorting column and m.merchantName as secondary. hence, it looks like its working with only one column while its sorting first with p.sp and then m.merchantName

Comment: but i want two type of sorting ( "ASC" AND "DESC") , In other words i want two type of different sorting in mysql query

Comment: ASC is default whether you write or not

Comment: so you means to say that i have to use order by if i want to use "DESC" and if i want to use "DESC" then i can use "," (comma) and then i can sort with multiple columns , am i right ?

Comment: No just go through this link - https://www.techbeamers.com/mysql-order-by/ carefully, you will find you answer

Comment: can you write query if there is something wrong with my query ? or no need to change query (its working fine) ?

Comment: everything seems to be correct, just replace your order by with this ->  order by m.merchantName, p.sp DESC  LIMIT 100

Comment: Bearanwal : and if i want to sort merchantName with "ASC" order then ? what will be query ?

Comment: looks like you haven't checked it yet, this will work in that case

Comment: means no need to change in query , am i right ?

Comment: i don't think so if its giving desired result , but you can change the formatting of the query like MYSQL keywords should be written in UPPERCASE and somewhere you have used `` backticks and so on... make it clean and clear, only then you'll be able to understand the query properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235575/discussion-between-adarsh-baranwal-and-ritika).